# auto-pst-pdf could not create pdf file

Tags: floats, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf

I want to include numerous graphs for my thesis. Recently, I learnt that we can format text and labels in LaTeX font using `psfrag`

I use Texstudio with pdflatex and as such i had to enable --shell-escape.
However, there seems to be some sort of error when creating the pdf file using `auto-pst-pdf`. I get the error that the -pics.pdf file is not created and hence there is no output.

I also tried `pstool`. Here the graph is replicated, but I am unable to alter any of the text or labels. So I think there is some sort of error somewhere in between the creation of the `pdf` file from an `.eps` file.

Below my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{psfrag}
%\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}

    \centering
    \psfrag{0}{$0$}
    \psfrag{10}{$10$}
    \includegraphics{loadings.eps}
    \label{loadings}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried to alter the x-axis labels and I tried it for several plots, however, none of them seem to work. So I think i have some error somewhere.

I checked the `log-file` and I post a part where I think the error occurs.

```
runsystem(echo " ")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(del "test-autopp.log")...executed.

runsystem(del "test-autopp.dvi")...executed.

runsystem(del "test-autopp.ps")...executed.

runsystem(del "test-autopp.pdf")...executed.

runsystem(latex -disable-write18 -jobname="test-autopp" -interaction=batchmode 
 "\let \APPmakepictures \empty \input  test.tex")...executed.

runsystem(dvips -Ppdf -o "test-autopp.ps" "test-autopp.dvi")...executed.

runsystem(ps2pdf  "test-autopp.ps" "test-autopp.pdf")...executed.

runsystem(pdfcrop  "test-autopp.pdf" "test-pics.pdf")...executed.



Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of test-pics.pdf failed.
This warning occured on input line 124.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Could not create test-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
This warning occured on input line 124.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.
```

Somehow there is a failure in the process of generating the pdf files.

**EDIT** When I included the option `crop=off`, I was able to generate the graph. However, when i tried to alter the axis, nothing happened again, exactly the same problem as when I used the `pstool` package.

**EDIT 2.0**
When I run the MWE with the suggestions of Raaja, I somehow managed to get it working correctly. Again, when I want to include it in my main file I get a blank page as output. The associated log output:

```
    runsystem(echo " ")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(latex -disable-write18 -jobname=""Thesis Msc Jasper"-autopp" -interac
tion=batchmode  "\let \APPmakepictures \empty \input  "Thesis Msc Jasper".tex")
...executed.



Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of "Thesis Msc Jasper"-autopp.dvi failed.
This warning occured on input line 124.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Could not create "Thesis Msc Jasper"-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.

This warning occured on input line 124.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.


("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pst-pdf\pst-pdf
.sty"
Package: pst-pdf 2017/06/22 v1.2d PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)

("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxet
ex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvt
ex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\luatex85\luat
ex85.sty"
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)
\c@pspicture=\count153
Package pst-pdf Info: MODE: 1 (pdfTeX mode) on input line 214.

("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pstricks\pstric
ks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2017/09/17 v0.65 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\iftex\iftex.sty
"
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)
("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\pst-x
key.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
)
("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pstr
icks.tex"
```

I think the error is again at the same point as previously. Somehow, it fails to correctly generate the pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `auto-pst-pdf` package explicitly and instead of `\includegraphics` you could use `\psfragfig{}` to achieve what you want as shown below:

```
%&pdflatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    {
        \psfrag{<org>}[<pos>][]{<replacement>}
        \psfragfig[<figure_def>]{<your_figure>.eps}
    }
    \caption{your caption}
    \label{your label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Also, to the best of my knowledge you dont need `pstool` here.

For more info on `psfrag` package and its usage its worth to refer: http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf

**Update 1:**

If a mixture of `.pdf` and `.eps` are being used, then make sure to encapsulate everything insdie `{...}` as shown below:

> > The `psfrag` environment

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        {
            \psfrag{<org>}[<pos>][]{<replacement>}
            \psfragfig[<figure_def>]{<your_figure>.eps}
        }
        \caption{your caption}
        \label{your label}
    \end{figure}
```

> > The `.pdf` environment

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        {
            \includegraphics[<figure_def>]{<your_figure>.pdf}
        }
        \caption{your caption}
        \label{your label}
    \end{figure}
```

By doing this, you will not see empty figure boxes due to `dvips` failing to read the figures due to mix of both `.pdf` and `.eps`.

Comment: When I adapt it to \psfragfig the output is blank. However, Latex exited without errors. I have no clue as to why it cannot depict the graph.

Comment: @J.P.1996 try removing your previous `.aux` files (others that were generated from the previous run), then make sure you not only adjust `\psfragfig` but also adapt your headers. Also, make sure your graphics path is correctly set. Then I do suppose, it should work properly. And, I suppose you are using `MikTex` distribution.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but I still got no output, except for a blank page. I managed to get output using  `\includegraphics`. So eventually, I had this MWE working correctly, although I had to use the option `[crop=off]` in the package `auto-pst-pdf`.  I was wondering if it clashes with other packages, because when I wanted to include it in my main Tex file, I again got the same error as before..

Comment: @J.P.1996 could you show what your `log` entries says?

Comment: Do you mean my log file?

Comment: @J.P.1996 yes sorry for the typo.

Comment: I have included the part of the log file where I think the error occurs. The main difference is that `\psfragfig` just continues as if there is no error, whereas the  log file shows the same error as when I used `\includegraphics`. Again the MWE is working just fine, for both methods..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85333/discussion-between-raaja-and-j-p-1996).

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the answer of Raaja.

It is important to have a filename without spaces. I tried several `test.tex` and for example `loadings plot.tex` files and for `test.tex` everything was fine, but for `loadings plot.tex` the plots disappeared.